# K8s - Metricbeat sending data but Filebeat doesn't to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, kibana, filebeat

*SOS*
I'm trying to deploy ELK stack on my Kubernetes**a

ElasticSearch, Metricbeat, Filebeat and Kibana running on Kubernetes, but in Kibana there is `no Filebeat index logs`
Kibana accessable: **URL** [here](http://logging.halykmart.online/)
Only **[MetricBeat](http://logging.halykmart.online/app/kibana#/management/elasticsearch/index_management/home?_g=())** index available

[image]

**I don't know where the issue please help me to figure out.
Any idea???**

**Pods**:

```
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
counter                               1/1     Running   0          21h
es-mono-0                             1/1     Running   0          19h
filebeat-4446k                        1/1     Running   0          11m
filebeat-fwb57                        1/1     Running   0          11m
filebeat-mk5wl                        1/1     Running   0          11m
filebeat-pm8xd                        1/1     Running   0          11m
kibana-86d8ccc6bb-76bwq               1/1     Running   0          24h
logstash-deployment-8ffbcc994-bcw5n   1/1     Running   0          24h
metricbeat-4s5tx                      1/1     Running   0          21h
metricbeat-sgf8h                      1/1     Running   0          21h
metricbeat-tfv5d                      1/1     Running   0          21h
metricbeat-z8rnm                      1/1     Running   0          21h
```

**SVC**

```
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                         AGE
elasticsearch      LoadBalancer   10.245.83.99     159.223.240.9   9200:31872/TCP,9300:30997/TCP   19h
kibana             NodePort       10.245.229.75    <none>          5601:32040/TCP                  24h
kibana-external    LoadBalancer   10.245.184.232   <pending>       80:31646/TCP                    24h
logstash-service   ClusterIP      10.245.113.154   <none>          5044/TCP                        24h
```

**Logstash logs [logstash (Raw)](https://github.com/shukurew/logs/blob/main/logs.logstash)**

**filebeat [logs (Raw)](https://github.com/shukurew/logs/blob/main/logs.filebeat-4446k)**

`kibana.yaml`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    run: kibana
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kibana
        image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.5.4
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
          value: http://elasticsearch.elk:9200/
        - name: XPACK_SECURITY_ENABLED
          value: "true"
        #- name: CLUSTER_NAME
         # value: elasticsearch
        #resources:
        #  limits:
        #    cpu: 1000m
        #  requests:
        #    cpu: 500m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5601
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
      #volumes:
      #  - name: logtrail-config
      #    configMap:
      #      name: logtrail-config
            


---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    #service: kibana
    run: kibana
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    run: kibana
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    targetPort: 5601

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-external
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: kibana
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 5601
```

`filebeat.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: filebeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: filebeat
  namespace: elk
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: filebeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-config
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  filebeat.yml: |-
    filebeat.config:
      prospectors:
        # Mounted `filebeat-prospectors` configmap:
        path: ${path.config}/prospectors.d/*.yml
        # Reload prospectors configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
      modules:
        path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
        # Reload module configs as they change:
        reload.enabled: false
    output.logstash:
      hosts: ['logstash-service:5044']
    setup.kibana.host: "http://kibana.elk:5601"
    setup.kibana.protocol: "http"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: filebeat-prospectors
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
data:
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - type: docker
      containers.ids:
      - "*"
      processors:
        - add_kubernetes_metadata:
            in_cluster: true
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: filebeat
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: filebeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: filebeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: filebeat
  
  
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: filebeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      containers:
      - name: filebeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:6.5.4
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/filebeat.yml",
          "-e",
        ]
        env:
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/filebeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: filebeat.yml
        - name: prospectors
          mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/prospectors.d
          readOnly: true
        #- name: data
        #  mountPath: /usr/share/filebeat/data
          subPath: filebeat/
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-config
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
      - name: prospectors
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: filebeat-prospectors
      #- name: data
      #  persistentVolumeClaim:
      #    claimName: elk-pvc

---
```

`Metricbeat.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metricbeat-config
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
data:
  metricbeat.yml: |-
    metricbeat.config.modules:
      # Mounted `metricbeat-daemonset-modules` configmap:
      path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
      # Reload module configs as they change:
      reload.enabled: false
    processors:
      - add_cloud_metadata:
    cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
    cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}
    output.elasticsearch:
      hosts: ['${ELASTICSEARCH_HOST:elasticsearch}:${ELASTICSEARCH_PORT:9200}']
      username: ${ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME}
      password: ${ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD}
    setup.kibana:
      host: "kibana.elk:5601"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metricbeat-daemonset-modules
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
data:
  system.yml: |-
    - module: system
      period: 10s
      metricsets:
        - cpu
        - load
        - memory
        - network
        - process
        - process_summary
        #- core
        #- diskio
        #- socket
      processes: ['.*']
      process.include_top_n:
        by_cpu: 5      # include top 5 processes by CPU
        by_memory: 5   # include top 5 processes by memory

    - module: system
      period: 1m
      metricsets:
        - filesystem
        - fsstat
      processors:
      - drop_event.when.regexp:
          system.filesystem.mount_point: '^/(sys|cgroup|proc|dev|etc|host|lib)($|/)'
  kubernetes.yml: |-
    - module: kubernetes
      metricsets:
        - node
        - system
        - pod
        - container
        - volume
      period: 10s
      hosts: ["localhost:10255"]
---
# Deploy a Metricbeat instance per node for node metrics retrieval
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metricbeat
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metricbeat
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: metricbeat
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      hostNetwork: true
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet
      containers:
      - name: metricbeat
        image: docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:6.5.4
        args: [
          "-c", "/etc/metricbeat.yml",
          "-e",
          "-system.hostfs=/hostfs",
        ]
        env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
          value: elasticsearch
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
          value: "9200"
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME
          value: elastic
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD
          value: changeme
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID
          value:
        - name: ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH
          value:
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 100Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config
          mountPath: /etc/metricbeat.yml
          readOnly: true
          subPath: metricbeat.yml
        - name: modules
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/modules.d
          readOnly: true
        - name: dockersock
          mountPath: /var/run/docker.sock
        - name: proc
          mountPath: /hostfs/proc
          readOnly: true
        - name: cgroup
          mountPath: /hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup
          readOnly: true
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/metricbeat/data
          subPath: metricbeat/
      volumes:
      - name: proc
        hostPath:
          path: /proc
      - name: cgroup
        hostPath:
          path: /sys/fs/cgroup
      - name: dockersock
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run/docker.sock
      - name: config
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-config
      - name: modules
        configMap:
          defaultMode: 0600
          name: metricbeat-daemonset-modules
      - name: data
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: elk-pvc

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: elk
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: metricbeat
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources:
  - namespaces
  - events
  - pods
  verbs:
  - get
  - watch
  - list
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: metricbeat
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    k8s-app: metricbeat
```

`Logstash.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: logstash-configmap
  namespace: elk
data:
  logstash.yml: |
    http.host: "0.0.0.0"
    path.config: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
  logstash.conf: |
    input {
      beats {
        port => 5044
      }
    }
    filter {
      grok {
          match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
      }
      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z" ]
      }
      geoip {
          source => "clientip"
        }
      }
      output {
        elasticsearch {
          hosts => ["elasticsearch.elk:9200"]
      }
    }

---


apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: logstash-deployment
  namespace: elk
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: logstash
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: logstash
  
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: logstash
        image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.3.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5044
        volumeMounts:
          - name: config-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/config
          - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
            mountPath: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.yml
              path: logstash.yml
      - name: logstash-pipeline-volume
        configMap:
          name: logstash-configmap
          items:
            - key: logstash.conf
              path: logstash.conf

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: logstash-service
  namespace: elk
spec:
  selector:
    app: logstash
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5044
    targetPort: 5044
```

**Full src files[(GitHub)](https://github.com/shukurew/ELK-Stack-kubernetes)**

Comment: How does your Logstash config look like?

Comment: @Val I've added please check

Comment: Why are you not using the same env variables `ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` in your Logstash config?

Comment: Are you able to reach logstash host on port 9600: `http://<logstash_host>:9600/_node/stats?pretty`? What do you get?

Comment: @Val I tried to use same config `ELASTICSEARCH_HOST` same no index in Kibana

Comment: Also see my last comment

Comment: @Val `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shukurew/logs/main/_node-stats` I got this log 
[link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/shukurew/logs/main/_node-stats)

Comment: `"events":{"in":0,"filtered":0,"out":0}` nothing comes into your pipeline, so Logstash is not the issue

Comment: @Val Any idea what may cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use FluentD as log transportation
`fluentd.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    app: fluentd
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - namespaces
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: fluentd
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: fluentd
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elk
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: elk
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: fluentd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: fluentd
    spec:
      serviceAccount: fluentd
      serviceAccountName: fluentd
      tolerations:
      - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        effect: NoSchedule
      containers:
      - name: fluentd
        image: fluent/fluentd-kubernetes-daemonset:v1.4.2-debian-elasticsearch-1.1
        env:
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST
            value: "elasticsearch.elk.svc.cluster.local"
          - name:  FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_PORT
            value: "9200"
          - name: FLUENT_ELASTICSEARCH_SCHEME
            value: "http"
          - name: FLUENTD_SYSTEMD_CONF
            value: disable
          - name: FLUENT_CONTAINER_TAIL_PARSER_TYPE
            value: /^(?<time>.+) (?<stream>stdout|stderr) [^ ]* (?<log>.*)$/
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 512Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 100Mi
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varlog
          mountPath: /var/log
        - name: varlibdockercontainers
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker/containers
          readOnly: true
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: varlog
        hostPath:
          path: /var/log
      - name: varlibdockercontainers
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker/containers
```